# XDG desktop/menu files and XFCE

Tags: xfce, xdg

I've been using XFCE for about a week now; I finally gave up on KDE on my desktop because of too many problems with the set-up there (switching between multiple users with multiple X servers running different WM/DE combinations, three monitors and two videocards; it is this last part which seems to have hamstrung KDE when switching users/X instances).

Anyway, XFCE has proven to be very stable in that context, and has gotten me into using XDG files for panel menus, which seem to be very straightforward; I have a menu file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/1.0/menu.dtd">

<Menu>
        <Name>GoldilocksDE</Name>

        <AppDir>/home/goldilocks/xdg/applications</AppDir>

        <Include>
                <Category>Goldilocks-favourites</Category>
        </Include>

</Menu>
```

Then everytime I want to add an app to that list, I just stick its desktop file in `/home/goldilocks/xdg/applications` and it is added to the menu without having to reload, restart, or do anything further.  Very nice.

For the most part, I've just been copying these in from `/usr/share/applications`, and adding `Goldilocks-favourites` to `Categories`.

There's still the default panel menu with a bunch of submenus that contains everything and I'm not bothering with editing that or using `xdg-desktop-menu`; the customized menu above is just for the half dozen or so things I use most often.  I'm using a custom path instead of `~/.local/share/applications` since the system/installers/the package manager uses that.  I've copied entries out of there too.

But now I am confused.  I tried to copy in an entry for `okular`; there's two on the system I could find, one left behind in `/usr/share/appplications/kde4` (actually there's a bunch of `okularApplication_foo.desktop` ones in there that seem to be about different mime types), and one in `~/.local/share/applications`.  Neither of them work when copied into the custom `/home/goldilocks/xdg/applications`.  I also took one for an application which does work and just replaced a few values appropriately.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Okular
Comment=Document viewer
Exec=okular
Icon=okular
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Goldilocks-favourites
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

No dice.  It is just not in the menu.  XFCE does not seem to log errors or anything anywhere AFAICT (there's nothing in `/var/log/syslog`, and I get a copy of anything using syslog dumped there; journald runs mostly castrated and never shows anything additional to that).

So I've been looking at the man pages found with `apropos xdg`, there's not much there, and [this freedesktop page](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s02.html) makes the format sound as simple and open as I think it is, with the exception of *"the 'reverse DNS' convention e.g. org.example.FooViewer.desktop"* which **none** of the desktop files on the system have followed anyway.  I also can't seem to find the Okular.desktop file that the big default menu (`/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu`) uses despite having [read this](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html#menu-file-format) and noted the contents of `env | grep XDG`.  It doesn't seem to be one of the the files mentioned above, since if I tweak them (e.g., change the icon) it doesn't affect the menu.

Does anyone understand what the issue is here?

Comment: Could it be that there's another desktop file for Okular that gets picked by Xfce, masking the one you expect?

Comment: @Nasha Well it obviously picks up one from somewhere because it's in the main menu hierarchy, although as mentioned I don't think it's either of the versions I could find.  However, almost everything in "my menu" is duplicated in the main one, and that's not an issue for that stuff.  Also,  the *only* place it should look for the stuff in my menu, if I understand things correctly, is what's specified in `<AppDir>`.

Comment: That said the desktop file might be not named "Okular.desktop" at all. Have you tried `locate .desktop | xargs grep -i okular`, just in case ?

Comment: As it turns out there's *dozens* of .desktop entries for okular in `/usr/share/kde4` (which must have been left over from purging it via the package manager), but I doubt those are in play -- digging around in this stuff I think KDE uses some of its own extensions to XDG, and that what that's about.  Anyway, I tried moving the whole directory, and same situation (no okular in my menu but it is still there in the main xfce one).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer as it does not include an explanation of why this should be the case for some desktop files but not others, but after a reboot this morning the okular entry was there.

The system had been up for more than a week, probably preceding my switch from KDE to XFCE.  However, I noticed the same problem immediately when adding an entry for `sylpheed`, and since nothing else was going on at that point,<sup>1</sup> logged in and out of XFCE and presto, there was sylpheed.

Note that I have minified the entries -- the okular one above doesn't include mime types, etc. -- and they are all very similar in most respects, so I don't see a cause there.

---

<sup>1. I don't use session management with anything since I've never found a restoration system that didn't include some kind of screw-up. Meaning logging in and out can be a PITA for me.</sup>

Comment: Bit of a note about okular in particular although it really doesn't involve the question:  Turns out without some KDE component installed and running it isn't stable, and this is by design :( Shame, nicest PDF viewer I've ever used.